# Confused about open and closed sets

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I am slightly confused about part of a problem about open and closed sets, from Stephen Abbott's *Understanding Analysis*. Consider the set $A = \{ 1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{9} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n^2} : n \in \mathbb{N} \}.$ Obviously the set is not closed, because $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges. What I'm confused about is the fact that $A^c = (-\infty) \cup (1 , 1+\frac 14) \cup (1+\frac 14, 1+\frac 14 + \frac 19)\cup ......\cup (\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1{k^2}, \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac 1{k^2})$. This seems to be a union of open sets, which should be open. But clearly, if $A^{\mathsf{c}}$ was open, then $A$ would be closed, which it is not. What am I missing here?

Comment: You're missing $\pi^2/6\in A^{\mathsf{c}}$.

Comment: The interval $$ \left[ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}, \infty \right) = \left[ \frac{\pi^2}{6},\infty \right) $$ is part of that union.

Comment: Also, the intervals in your union seem to be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But $A^{\mathsf{c}} \ne (-\infty, 1) \cup (1, 1+\frac{1}{4}) \cup (1 + \frac{1}{4}, 1 + \frac{1}{9}) \cup \cdots \cup (1+\frac{1}{n^2}, 1 + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}) \, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$[*]

You are omitting that $\{x| x > \sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1{n^2} \forall n \in \mathbb N\}\subset A^c$.

And $\{x| x > \sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1{n^2} \forall n \in \mathbb N\}\subset A^c = [\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1{n^2}, \infty)$ is a *closed* set.